# How to debug library in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode5

I am new to Xcode and Mac world. I usually work in VC++ using Visual Studio. As in Visual Studio, we can attach a process to `.lib` or `.dll` code, is there any way to attach process and debug library `(.a)` code in Xcode?

Regards

Comment: One way is to add the library XCode project inside the application or use the library source files present and debug. For this library source files should be there. Also make sure you use debug mode in XCode.

Comment: @user2071152 I have library files present, but how to debug. Means I wanted to step-in into code.

Comment: As i earlier mentioned copy all the library source file to your application or Add the XCode project of library project into your application.

Comment: @user2071152 Thanks for quick response. Please suggest, how to add project in application?

Comment: Use the File Menu option and use Add Files to

Comment: @user2071152 Your solution works for me. Can you please paste as answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. I have posted this as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add library XCode project inside the application or use the library source files inside the application. This requires the availability of library source files. Also make sure to use debug mode in XCode.

You can use the Menu option File -> Add Files to option to add files to XCode project.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Workspace (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html) and add the Library-Project and your Project to it (Drag & Drop). After some configurations (Youtube is full of tutorials) you can set breakpoints in the library code.